# discrete cosine transform in matlab

Tags: matlab, dct

In the matlab code, i apply the discrete cosine transform in an image,after applying the dct, the file size of the dct image is increased from the original file size.Is it true without applying quantization and entropy coding,the file size of the dct image is normally high?

Answer (score 1):

The DCT alone effectively doubles the amount of storage required for an image. 8-bit samples require 16-bits after the DCT.